# SOLR enum fieldType

Tags: solr, solr4

I need to index a field called `lang` that will contain values such as `en` or `ar`
I need its type to be `enum` is there a way to do it in `schema.xml` file?
or I should simply use a normal text field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an Enum support in solr - please take a look at this [Working with enums](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+Enum+Fields)

Comment: yup .. this is now .. SOLR-5084
Fix Version/s: 4.6, 5.0

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47308076/creating-enumtype-solr-using-solrj

Answer (score 2):

There is no enum field, you can just go ahead with the non analyzed and tokenized string field instead of text field

**UPDATE** - Enum is now supported with SOLR-5084 Fix Version/s: 4.6, 5.0 and above.