# Creating EnumType Solr using SolrJ

Tags: solr, solrj

I need to create a schema which will containt few enums. I'm trying to do that using SolrJ.
I've found this link [DefininganEnumFieldinschema](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/working-with-enum-fields.html#WorkingwithEnumFields-DefininganEnumFieldinschema.xml) but I couldn't find any examples using Schema API or SolrJ.

Here is my enum:

```
public enum Attributes {
    SPONSORED("sponsored"),

    TOP_RATED("top-rated"),

    GENERIC("generic"),

    PROMOTION("promotion"),

    QUICK_ORDER("quick-order");

    private String value;

    Attributes(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    @JsonValue
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static Attributes fromValue(String text) {
        for (Attributes b : Attributes.values()) {
            if (String.valueOf(b.value).equals(text)) {
                return b;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And I want to add a field to my schema using SolrJ:

```
Map<String, Object> fieldAttributes = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    fieldAttributes.put("name", "address.**attributes**");
    fieldAttributes.put("type", "**attributesEnum**");
    fieldAttributes.put("stored", true);
    SchemaRequest.AddField addFieldRequest = new SchemaRequest.AddField(fieldAttributes);

    addFieldRequest.process(client);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to specify your enum field in schema, like in the documentation:

```
<fieldType name="myEnumField" class="solr.EnumField" enumsConfig="enumsConfig.xml" enumName="attribute"/>
```

in the enumsConfig.xml you will specify all your enum values, like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<enumsConfig>
  <enum name="attribute">
    <value>sponsored</value>
    <value>generic</value>
  </enum>
</enumsConfig>
```

Alternatively, you could create this fieldType dynamically via Schema API as follows:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
  "add-field-type" : {
     "name":"myEnumField",
     "class":"solr.EnumField",
     "enumsConfig":"enumsConfig.xml",
     "enumName" : "attribute"}
}' http://localhost:8983/solr/demo/schema
```

You could do this as well in **SolrJ** fashion, by using `org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.schema.SchemaRequest.AddFieldType`, you need to specify [FieldTypeDefinition](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_6_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/request/schema/FieldTypeDefinition.html), method `setAttributes(Map<String,Object> attributes)` will be helpful